# Javascript srcElement property on IE9

Tags: javascript

I have some images in a `div` object, when mousedown event fired I use `n.srcElement` to catch the image object.

In Firefox it would be `n.target`

However `IE9` doesn't work on both `n.target` and `n.srcElement` because IE9 will return div object rather than image object when use `n.target` and `n.srcElement`.

Question is what property can be use on IE9 in order to get image object when click a image in  div object.

Comment: Show sample code that shows the problem. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I don't think that your observation is accurate. If you click on an `<img>` tag then IE9 will definitely report it as the target (srcElement) of the event.

Comment: I guess, you are not getting the `n` (`event`) object properly. [Refer this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: What element are you binding the event to?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're still using `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener` in IE9? Showing some of your code would definitely help.

Comment: if (document.addEventListener) {
               mydiv.addEventListener("mousedown",mousedown, false);
 }else {
               mydiv.attachEvent("mousedown", mousedown);
       }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you bind div element rather than image and use mouse event, you will get image object if you click on image by using n.target (firefox) or n.srcElement.
IE 9 you will need to use window.event.srcElement to get the object you just click.